# Changing the colours of only the children of the nodes in TreeView using pygtk?

Tags: python-2.7, treeview, pygtk

I have created a `TreeView` and was able to alternate the *colors* of the nodes in the tree. How do I assign a different *color* to the children (`InnerBlocks`) of the nodes to make them stand out?

Answer (score 0):

**There isn't a solution available to this specific problem.**

If you're looking for a way to make the **nodes stand out**, you can use alternating colours for the all the nodes (**including the parent nodes**).

```
gtk.rc_parse_string( """
             style "custom-treestyle"{
                     GtkTreeView::odd-row-color = "#f0f0f0"
                     GtkTreeView::even-row-color = "#ddedf4"
                     GtkTreeView::allow-rules = 1
             }
             widget "*custom_treeview*" style "custom-treestyle"
             """)
```